# how to write web reference file in python similar to the one we used to write in C# .net?

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds, web-reference

i am looking for a method to write web reference file in python similar to the one  we used to write in C# .net??
i am looking on writing reference for WSDL files in this .Can anyone suggest any suitable ways